# Extjs DragDrop with Grouping Grid when 'dropPosition=after' throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid with grouping functionality, when I drop a record from second grid 'after' the last record in last group I get an error:

I am using extjs `4.2.5.1763`

[image]

[image]

```js
view.on('beforedrop', function(node, data, overModel, dropPosition, dropHandlers) {
...
...
...
});
```

When the `dropPosition` is `after` I got the error (only in last group) and when it is `before` it works as expected.

For other groups in the grid It just adding the record to the next below group, and I think this is related to the last group: it's trying to add it to next group and there is not next group.

The idea is to copy the record to the destination group no matter if the user `drop` the record `before` or `after` any record in the destination grid, and I can't control the end users sometimes they may drop `after`.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: If you can provide the fiddle. Helps us to look into it quickly